# Swift - Facebook Graph API: Cannot get "from" field in comment for a live video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, live-video

I'm pretty new in swift development, if I do some noob mistakes sorry.

So I'm trying to get all comments from a live video which is on a page ("/{live-video-id}/comments). I have a response with "created_time", "message" and "id" field but I don't have the "from" field with the author's "name" and "id".

I have "manage_page" and "publish_page" as permission.

How can I get the "from" field please ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested comments of Page Posts of a Page i manage and it worked fine. You need to make sure not to use a User Token, but a **Page Token** instead. Authorizing with `manage_pages` is required, but you still need a Page Token after authorization: `/page-id?fields=access_token`

Comment: Thanks you luschn ! Your reply helped me a lot ! You're right I didn't use the Page Token.